# why I receive nothing to commit, working tree clean in the middle of reverting?

Tags: git

I was trying to revert bunch of commits but I receive `nothing to commit, working tree is clean` message in the middle of reverting process and I just used `git revert --continue` and reverting finished but some of my commits got dropped, so I wonder why this message popped up in this specific scenario and why some of my commits got dropped?

P.N: for example L and H are dropped in here...

command:

```
git revert 5673a~1..80f1d (head is currently pointing to test branch)
```

diagrams:

```
 | * 80f1d90 M
 | * c666151 L
 | *   14aed05 K
 | |\
 | | * db8fb8c J
 | | * 79fa382 I
 | * | a1fde5a H
 | |/
 | * 05e10f7 G
 | * 491a795 F
 |/
 * 29f74bc E
 | * 60174fb (HEAD -> test) D 
 | * bdad508 C
 |/
 * a884ffa B
 * 5673a97 A
```

after reverting:

```
 | * 657hkl8 N
 | * 80f1d90 M
 | * c666151 L
 | *   14aed05 K
 | |\
 | | * db8fb8c J
 | | * 79fa382 I
 | * | a1fde5a H
 | |/
 | * 05e10f7 G
 | * 491a795 F
 |/
 * 29f74bc E
 |
 | * 98d9fbf (HEAD -> test) Revert "B"
 | * fe62bd1 Revert "F"
 | * 82e2bc4 Revert "G"
 | * 48b0f90 Revert "I"
 | * bb2dfaf Revert "J"
 | * 918f4e8 Revert "K"
 | * c231e61 Revert "M"
 | * 60174fb D
 | * bdad508 C
 |/
 * a884ffa B
 * 5673a97 A
```

log message:

```
 $ git revert --continue
 [test 60174fb] Revert "M"
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)
 On branch test
 Revert currently in progress.
 (run "git revert --continue" to continue)
 (use "git revert --skip" to skip this patch)
 (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

 nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: This implies that your working directory matches the commit you reverted to.  It should just be an ignorable status message.

Comment: but it's drooping my commit ... and I want them... what about those? @TimRoberts

Comment: It means that the revert introduces a change that is already in current state. It looks like your commits C and D are some squashed versions of some parts of the history between A and N.

Comment: It is also inexplicable how you got a "Revert D" at the tip of branch test.

Comment: is there any way to keep them? @j6t

Comment: These reversals do not introduce any change anymore. You could make empty commits with a suitable commit message using `git commit --allow-empty`, but why would you want to?

Comment: just out of curiosity I asked, and tnx for answer @j6t